# Derivative of a piecewise function at its endpoints

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have a function $f(x)= \begin{cases} 3-(x+1)^2 & \text{if } x\leq0, \\ 1+(x-1)^2 & \text{if } x \geq 0. \end{cases}$ and I want to evaluate $f'(0)$. If I differentiate,$f'(x)= \begin{cases} -2x-2 & \text{if } x\leq0, \\ 2x-2 & \text{if } x \geq 0. \end{cases}$ and we can see at $f'(0)$, both are $-2$. Does this mean I can conclude that $f'(0)=-2$?

Can I take this to the general case, such that if I have two  sufficiently well-behaved cases in my piece wise function(continuous at endpoint etc), and I want to evaluate the derivative of the function at their endpoint, is it sufficient for the derivative of both "pieces" to be the same at that point for me to conclude that the derivative of the function at that point exists and is equal to the value calculated?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
h(x)  \ , \ x \geq 0,\\
g(x)  \ , \ x \leq 0,
\end{cases}
$$
where $h$ and $g$ are differentiable at $0$. This means that there exist the following limits
$$
h'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x},
$$
$$
g'(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}.
$$
Notice now that
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}\frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{h(x)-h(0)}{x}=h'(0)
$$
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-}\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}=g'(0).
$$
Since both limits exist and we are supposing $h'(0)=g'(0)$ we have that the following limit exist
$$
f'(0)=\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=h'(0)=g'(0).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since $f$ is continuous at $0$ and since your computations show that the left derivative of $f$ at $0$ is equal to the right derivative of $f$ at $0$.